# runtime assertion error while operating on vector c++

Tags: c++, stl, runtime, erase, assertion

i have an array **arr** of vectors and I want to search and remove from the array vectors which have a specific value in one of elements, call it **elementA**. It happens to me, that if you have a look inside the array, such condition is fullfilled for a couple of consecutive vectors in a row.

Comment: Which line in your code is failing the assertion? And can you show the declaration of `arr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
int eStart = -1; int eEnd = -1; 
for ( int i=0; i<arr.size()-1; i++ )
{
    if ( -1 == eStart && arr[i].getElementA() == 0 )
        eStart = i;
    if ( arr[i].getElementA() == 0 )
        eEnd = i;
}
arr.erase( arr.begin()+eStart, arr.begin()+eEnd );
```

The second iterator passed to erase have to be One past the last you want to erase (and call erase only if you finded some element that need to be erase):

```
arr.erase( arr.begin()+eStart, arr.begin()+eEnd +1 );
```

The error: checking the "range of iterators" during arithmetic’s: the result have to be `>=` the first element, and `<=` the last element. `begin()-1` don't fit: that is what you have when you don’t check if finded, that is when `eRtart=-1`.

```
_SCL_SECURE_VALIDATE_RANGE(
        _Myptr + _Off <= ((_Myvec *)(this->_Getmycont()))->_Mylast &&
        _Myptr + _Off >= ((_Myvec *)(this->_Getmycont()))->_Myfirst);
    _Myptr += _Off;
```

NOTE: It is not recomended to inherit from std::containers.

Comment: why one past the last? begin() points to first element, which has indice 0, so if I add eEnd to begin() I obtain exactly the right indice I think ..

Comment: @eReM All `std` functions which take iterator ranges take arguments "iterator to first element in range" and "iterator one past last element in range." Or, mathematically, `[first, last)`.

Comment: sure, I mixed indexes and elements, thought if I want to point to ith element I have to use i-1th index.

Answer (score 1):

```
int eStart = -1; int eEnd = -1; 
for ( int i=0; i<arr.size()-1; i++ )
{
    if ( -1 == eStart && arr[i].getElementA() == 0 )
        eStart = i;
    if ( arr[i].getElementA() == 0 )
        eEnd = i;
}
if(estart != -1)    // added check <---------------------------------
    arr.erase( arr.begin()+eStart, arr.begin()+eEnd );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [remove-erase idioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to simplify your code:

```
struct IsZeroA
{
  IsZeroA() {}
  bool operator()(ClassA a) 
  {
    return a.getElementA() == 0;
  }
};

arr.erase(std::remove_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(), IsZeroA()), arr.end());
```

OR use lambda if you use C++11

```
arr.erase(std::remove(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 
         [](const ClassA& a){ return a.getElementA() == 0; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Now we don’t need to review your code, but provide a „general“ solution.

I understand you explicitly want to take advantage of the fact that the elements to erase are consecutive.

We will use the predicate `IsZeroA` introduced by **@billz**.

```
auto first=find_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(), IsZero()  );
if(first!=arr.end())
{
    auto last= find_if_not(first, arr.end(), IsZero()  );
    arr.erase(first,last);
}
```

It can be reduced to:

```
auto  first = find_if  (arr.begin(), arr.end(), IsZero()  );
arr.erase( first, find_if_not(first, arr.end(), IsZero()) );
```

Comment: @josh130 : Do these two line (plus the pdefined predicat) solved the problem?

Comment: sorry i was not notified by your question. the first answer of yours solved the problem, thanks!